# ailed to boot after interrupted upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade

Today morning, I started an upgrade for my system (AcerTravelmate 4740) from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, on-line. All the packets downloaded and it started the upgrade. All of a sudden system went power-off on its own. And then fresh boot showed a screen saying kernel panicked etc.(similar to what mention here).

I read a lot of posts suggesting making a live CD/USB to use 'fsck' based commands .. .. I made a live USB with 13.04 (available at the moment) and followed the procedure, but, all in vain.

I would appreciate a kind help. Thanks.

Comment: os not starting

Comment: During a release-upgrade is the worst possible time for a poweroff. It means that your system has a mix of different-release packages that are incompatible, and the system may-or-may-not be recoverable at all. The easiest and fastest way to recover is to backup your data and clean-install 16.04. If you *really* want to learn how to fix it, then select an older kernel using GRUB and run a dist-upgrade. Might work, might not.

Comment: I would try what @user535733 suggested (using old kernel and if it boots, trying to continue the release-upgrade via dist-upgrade). You could restore back to 14.04 using backups & start again; or re-fsck & install 16.04* using something-else and don't format (it'll note added packages, erase system directories, install, add-back additional packages if available without touching user files; plus it allows you to skip a release; ie. you could do this with 18.04 though unity/gnome complicates this somewhat so skipping may not be great idea).  my 2c